# MySQL store PROCEDURE @ sign and As not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure in my SQL server, but it gives an error: As and @s are not valid. Why is this happening?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE getLocation
    (@location varchar(10) )
    AS
    SELECT Product, Quantity
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Warehouse = @location
```

Comment: That's *Microsoft SQL Server* syntax ... for *MySQL* lose the @/AS and wrap in a BEGIN/END (See the docs for CREATE PROCEDURE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the procedure parameters don't use @ prefix, use a custom prefix instead to avoid field conflict names:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getLocation
    (p_location varchar(10) )
BEGIN
    SELECT Product, Quantity
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Warehouse = p_location
END$$
```

Comment: Thank u above code for MS SQL-SEVER i found it. In my sql store procedures are different to MS SQL-SEVER Syntaxs